# How to assign a string value of a string object to another string object in jsp?

Tags: jsp

How to assign a string value of a `String` object to another `String` object in jsp?

If for example:

```
String a = rsobj.getString(1); // rsobj is ResultSet obj
String b = null;
```

Then how can I assign value of `a` to `b`.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What confuses you? Don't complicate the problem, it is same as you would do in a `.java` class.

```
b = a;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this :

```
String a=rsobj.getString(1); // rsobj is ResultSet obj
String b=a;
```